# Find sum of the column

Tags: javascript, php, html

[image: I have this table]I have the following table row:

```
<tr class="table-row">
  <td class="column-1">
    <div class="cart-img-product b-rad-4 o-f-hidden">
      <img src="../admin/uploads/<?php echo $info['product_photo']; ?>" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="column-2">
    <?php echo $info['product_name']; ?>
  </td>
  <td class="column-3"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $info['product_price']; ?>" readonly></td>
  <td class="column-4"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $info['product_amount']; ?> Piece" readonly></td>
  <td class="column-5"><input style="color:red;" type="text" value="Rs <?php echo $info['product_price']*$info['product_amount']; ?>" readonly></td>
</tr>
```

I want to get the sum of the last `td` which will be the total pricing. I thought of using js but as the row may get dynamically added it is hard. How can i get the total price.

I want the total to be displayed here.

```
<span class="m-text21 w-size20 w-full-sm">
   <strong><input type="text" id="total" value=""></strong>
</span>
```

Comment: But where you want to get that total price in js?

Comment: You've listed two programming languages, PHP and JavaScript.  Both are very capable of performing arithmetic operations.  You're currently showing PHP code, is that what you're going to use to calculate your sum?  What values are you summing?  What happens when you try to add them together?  Basically, what have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: `$(".table-row").find(':last-child').find("input").val();` should work in dynamic case

Comment: @RahulMeshram I want the last td values to sum up ar per how many rows will be there and i want to store the value anywhere from where i can display it as total prce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
let v = [...document.querySelectorAll('.column-5 input')];
total.value = v.reduce((a,c)=> +c.value.replace(/Rs /,'')+a, 0)
```

We use here standard: [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduc), [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (to cast NodeList to array - to have access to reduce), [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with simple [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) (to remove `Rs` prefix). The `v` contains array with `<input>` elements from last column for all rows. By`+` in `+c.val..` JS make implicit cast string to number.

```js
let v = [...document.querySelectorAll('.column-5 input')];
total.value = v.reduce((a,c)=> +c.value.replace(/Rs /,'')+a, 0)
```

```html
<table><tbody>
<tr class="table-row">
  <td class="column-1">
    <div class="cart-img-product b-rad-4 o-f-hidden">
      <img src="../admin/uploads/xxx" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="column-2">
    <?php echo $info['product_name']; ?>
  </td>
  <td class="column-3"><input type="text" value="10000" readonly></td>
  <td class="column-4"><input type="text" value="2 Piece" readonly></td>
  <td class="column-5"><input style="color:red;" type="text" value="Rs 20000" readonly></td>
</tr>

<tr class="table-row">
  <td class="column-1">
    <div class="cart-img-product b-rad-4 o-f-hidden">
      <img src="../admin/uploads/xxx" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="column-2">
    <?php echo $info['product_name']; ?>
  </td>
  <td class="column-3"><input type="text" value="14000" readonly></td>
  <td class="column-4"><input type="text" value="1 Piece" readonly></td>
  <td class="column-5"><input style="color:red;" type="text" value="Rs 14000" readonly></td>
</tr>
<tbody><table>

<span class="m-text21 w-size20 w-full-sm">
   <strong><input type="text" id="total" value=""></strong>
</span>
```

Comment: This is what i want but i didnt understand. Are those to be implemented as js.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `querySelectorAll()` and `forEach()` like the following way:

```js
var lastTDs = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr td:last-child input');
var sum = 0;
[...lastTDs].forEach(function(td) {
  sum += Number(td.value.split(' ')[1]);
});
console.log(sum);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="column-1">
          <div class="cart-img-product b-rad-4 o-f-hidden">
              <img src="../admin/uploads/<?php echo $info['product_photo']; ?>" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">
          </div>
      </td>
      <td class="column-2"><?php echo $info['product_name']; ?></td>
      <td class="column-3"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $info['product_price']; ?>" readonly></td>
      <td class="column-4"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $info['product_amount']; ?> Piece" readonly></td>
      <td class="column-5"><input style="color:red;" type="text" value="Rs 50" readonly></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="table-row">
      <td class="column-1">
          <div class="cart-img-product b-rad-4 o-f-hidden">
              <img src="../admin/uploads/<?php echo $info['product_photo']; ?>" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">
          </div>
      </td>
      <td class="column-2"><?php echo $info['product_name']; ?></td>
      <td class="column-3"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $info['product_price']; ?>" readonly></td>
      <td class="column-4"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $info['product_amount']; ?> Piece" readonly></td>
      <td class="column-5"><input style="color:red;" type="text" value="Rs 100" readonly></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```